# BigText Plugin not working when parent class is identified in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been using the following jquery plugin to set my font sizes based on the width of the container divs: http://www.zachleat.com/web/bigtext-makes-text-big/ I have been able to get it working with different fonts when I define the fonts in the css as

```
.bigtext{
    font-family:Arial
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/pF5bQ/3/

however, if I define the css with a parent class

```
.theme .bigtext{
    font-family:Arial
}
```

It sets the font too big.

see http://jsfiddle.net/pF5bQ/4/

The app I'm working on features various themes that use different fonts so I need to be able to define different styles for the bigtext based on the parent class.

Any ideas?

Comment: Added a comment https://github.com/zachleat/BigText/issues/20

Comment: This is now fixed in BigText. Get the new version at GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for keeping tabs on this thread! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a 'true' solution but the work around I ended up discovering was that if I applied my theme class to the same div as the big text, I'd get the desired result.

```
.theme.bigtext{
    font-family:Arial
}
```

It feels really hack-y because in the project I'm working on, I need to do the class switching and what not in javascript, but it gets the job done.

http://jsfiddle.net/pF5bQ/7/

Answer (score 0):

well you can try this hack I did lol

http://jsfiddle.net/pF5bQ/4/

```
.bigtext{
    font-family:arial
}

.theme .bigtext{
    font-family:arial;
    color:red;
}
```

edit: so if you put the .theme line inside of your theme css or whatever way you implement it, I think it will work as long as you have the original line lol This is all I can offer, I never used bigtext before

Comment: hah! That does make it work :) Thanks for your response. I'll leave it open so maybe someone who knows a little more can possibly explain why this happens. If not, I'll accept your answer in a couple hours :)

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work all the time. http://jsfiddle.net/pF5bQ/5/
I think somehow the plugin is checking the size of the div and making the font fit based on the .bigtext class. In the jsfiddle above, it doesn't fit because it seems the font is trying to fit inside the same space as the impact font

Comment: If I can't find a solution, I'm just going to set my bigtext font to be the widest font I need to account for :(

Comment: it works as long as the fonts are the same for both css rules, you can change css rule using javascript/jquery if there is any instance that they are different and you need to set it to the same to make the theme work

Comment: This is now fixed in BigText. Get the new version at GitHub.