# Problems with Bigtext for default case

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to get the Bigtext JQuery plugin to behave in an expected manner. If we take [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twashing/gpyj4/2/) as an example, I'd expect the font size of the text and title to adjust according the amount of text in the container.

I tried the ***".theme"*** class solution suggested in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504243/jquery-bigtext-plugin-not-working-when-parent-class-is-identified-in-css). But that didn't work. Is there something else I have to do to get this library to work?

```
.SO {
  won't let me post without some inlined code
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You're displaying the early symptoms of `div`itis. You should also try to cut down on the inline styles; it's cleaner to put them into the `<style>` tag, or a separate sheet. If inline code seems to be the only thing that works, try using CSS's `!important`.

Comment: The divs are not the problem. See this [pared down jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twashing/gpyj4/5/). I'm still not seeing the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem. It turns out that the library dynamically adds `<style>` elements to the document's head. I found this to only work in the simplest cases.

The main work of calculating font sizes, et al, is done in a function called **calculateSizes**. I just ended up extruding that function, and calling it directly. From there, I just took the calculated font sizes and applied them myself.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Bigtext can't work on more than one element in a page. I am working on an alternative version to fix that.